# See if word in column B on sheet 1 is 1 or 0, if 1 lookup word in sheet 2 in row 3 and return list below that word

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, offset

I have tried to fix a code from the answers that I have found in the forum, but I can't manage.

My issue is:

I have a list of recipes names in the sheet weeks, and I want to decide with a 1 or a 0 which ones I want to meal prep for next week. In sheet Recipes, I have the Recipes listed with their ingredients list below. I would like to have an output of what I need to shop in Sheet 5.
In sheet Weeks If column B = 1, take recipe name in column A; Hlookup recipe name in sheet Recipes row 3, and return list of ingredients below to sheet 3 (the shopping list).

```
Sub Output_Shoopinglist()

    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weeks")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  ' get last used row in column b
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim DataRange As Range  ' get data range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("B3", "C20" & LastRow)
    
    Dim DataArray() As Variant  ' read data into an array (for fast processing)
    DataArray = DataRange.Value
    
    Dim OutputData As Collection  ' create a collection where we collect all desired data
    Set OutputData = New Collection
    
    ' check each data row and if desired add to collection
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(DataArray, 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1)
        If DataArray(iRow, 2) = 1 Then
            OutputData.Add DataArray(iRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Recipes")
    
    Dim wsVolume As Worksheet
    Set wsVolume = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shopping list")
    
    'Lookup Value in Tab Recipes in row 3, and return Ingrediants list one below the other in tab Shopping list in Column B

'Here I am missing code:
              

End Sub
```

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is as far as I got..

Comment: So which part of your code is not working? Is the adding of words in `OutputData` working? Note: Your set of `DataRange` might be excessive - If `LastRow` is 100 then `ws.Range("B3", "C20" & LastRow)` actually means `B3:C20100`. You probably mean `ws.Range("B3:C" & LastRow)`.

Comment: Hi, I am missing the part where the recipe is looked up, and the ingredients in the rows below are copied and pasted.

Comment: Right, I assume you made an attempt so can you edit your question and include your best code attempt for that part? And your edited description and code don't really match up, (column B is the number and recipe name is column A but your `DataRange` is taking values from `B` and `C`?)

Comment: If you are looking for direction on how to approach your question, do a Range.Find on row 3 in sheet2 and if found, get value from found range's column.

Comment: Thank you Raymond, somehow I cannot figure it out tho...

Comment: I don't have a computer now but you will do something along the line of `Dim findCell As Range: Dim i As Long: For i = 1 to OutputData.Count: Set findCell = wsTemplate.Rows(3).Find(OutputData(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole): If Not findCell Is Nothing Then MsgBox findCell.Offset(1,).Value:  For i`. @annabelle_123

Comment: I should also mention that since we have no sight of what your worksheets look like and no visual example of your expected result, it's difficult to give you a proper answer that does exactly what you want. (E.g. where to paste the list of ingredients in Sheet3, the shopping list?) Are the Ingredients all written in just 1 cell in row 4 of Recipes sheet or 1 ingredient each cell?)

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that! I have added the screenshots! I will try the code thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have left comments in few area to explain what the code is doing in general.

As mentioned in the comment - The basic idea is to perform a `Find` method along the row containing the recipe name and if it is found, the column number of the found cell will be used to pull out the list of ingredients (and the amount that is 1 column before) that is written below the recipe names.

Once the list has been retrieved in an array, it will be used to write into the shopping list worksheet at once.

```
Option Explicit

Const WSNAME_WEEK As String = "Weeks"
Const WSNAME_RECIPES As String = "Recipes"
Const WSNAME_SHOPPING As String = "Shopping list"

Sub Output_Shoppinglist()

    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WSNAME_WEEK)
    
    Dim lastRow As Long  ' get last used row in column b
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim DataRange As Range  ' get data range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("B4:C" & lastRow)
    
    Dim DataArray() As Variant  ' read data into an array (for fast processing)
    DataArray = DataRange.Value
    
    Dim OutputData As Collection  ' create a collection where we collect all desired data
    Set OutputData = New Collection
    
    ' check each data row and if desired add to collection
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(DataArray, 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1)
        If DataArray(iRow, 2) = 1 Then
            OutputData.Add DataArray(iRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iRow
        
    If OutputData.Count <> 0 Then
'        Uncomment if you need to clear the shopping list prior to inserting this batch of list of ingredients
'        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WSNAME_SHOPPING)
'            Dim shoppingLastRow As Long
'            shoppingLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).Row
'            .Range("A2:B" & shoppingLastRow).Value = ""
'        End With
                
        '1. Loop through the collection,
        '2. Pass the recipe name to GetIngredients to retrieve the list of ingredients (in an array) from Recipes worksheet
        '3. Pass the array to WriteToShoppingList for writing into the Shopping list worksheet
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To OutputData.Count
            'Get the ingredient list from Recipes sheet
            Dim ingredList As Variant
            ingredList = GetIngredients(OutputData(i))
            
            If Not IsEmpty(ingredList) Then WriteToShoppingList ingredList
        Next i
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub

Function GetIngredients(argRecipeName As String) As Variant
    Const firstRow As Long = 7 'Change this to whichever row the first ingredient should be on
    Const recipesNameRow As Long = 3
    
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WSNAME_RECIPES)
            
    '==== Do a Find on row with the recipe names
    Dim findCell As Range
    Set findCell = wsTemplate.Rows(recipesNameRow).Find(argRecipeName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
    If Not findCell Is Nothing Then
        '==== If found, assign the value of the ingredients (from firstRow to the last row) into an array
        
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = wsTemplate.Cells(firstRow, findCell.Column).End(xlDown).Row
        
        Dim ingredRng As Range
        Set ingredRng = wsTemplate.Range(wsTemplate.Cells(firstRow, findCell.Column), wsTemplate.Cells(lastRow, findCell.Column)).Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2)
                        
        Dim ingredList As Variant
        ingredList = ingredRng.Value

        GetIngredients = ingredList
    End If        
End Function

Sub WriteToShoppingList(argIngredients As Variant)
    Dim wsVolume As Worksheet
    Set wsVolume = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WSNAME_SHOPPING)
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsVolume.Cells(wsVolume.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    wsVolume.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(argIngredients, 1), 2).Value = argIngredients
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so very very much for this!! You are a star!